# window.open should open only once in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This works fine with Mozilla Firefox. But in chrome it doesn't works for below scenario.

### Scenario:-

Open a new chrome browser A. Enter the code and execute. Click on the link. It opens new window B with the URL.  ( if I click the URL again it works fine in focus).But open another new browser C . open the code , click.URL. opens the new window D.

### Query:-

My query is I need to know it S possible when I click URL C.  Window B has to load again or focus there. It works in mozilla.

### Code:-

```
<a href=”JavaScript:void(0);” onClick=JavaScript:URL();return false;
function URL(){ Var win; if(win == null || win.closed) {
Win=window.open(URL,name,width and height); } else { Win.focus(); } }
```

Comment: <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onClick=JavaScript:URL();return false;
function URL(){
Var win;
if(win == null || win.closed)
{
Win=window.open(URL,name,width and height);
}
else
{
Win.focus();
}
}

Comment: The comment above, is that some code you'd like to add to your original question?

Comment: Yes Jasper the code is for that question , can yu get me solution for it ??

Comment: Can any one answer for this question pls !!